# Change inode number

Tags: itunes, command-line, filesystem

I have my music library on a .dmg for portability purposes. A while ago something happened to the file system on this disk but Disk Utility managed to rescue everything. However, one problem - all inode numbers were messed up and iTunes seems to prioritize inode number to the soft path to files. Now I have a couple of hundred files in my music library that points towards directories rather than files. I have to, in iTunes, manually change these pointers. This is the steps I have to take to achieve this:

1. Duplicate the directory.
2. Delete (rm -rf, putting them in the Trash is not enough) the original directory.
3. Cmd-I on the file in iTunes, who then complains that the file can't be found.
4. Locate the correct file in iTunes fila dialog
5. Rename the duplicated directory to the original name (iTunes falls back on paths if the inode number has changed).

This is a bit of PITA. Is there way to do something like "touch --assign-new-random-inode [name of directory]" so I don't need to duplicate and delete a lot of directories (easy to make a manual mistake here)?

Comment: An inode is kind of a low-level thing used by the filesystem to identify files and folders, iTunes doesn't care about that but relies on path and filenames instead (look inside `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music Library.xml` for details). So are you basically saying that you've restored your music files to a different path than before?

Comment: Why don't you simply disable automatic media management in iTunes (if necessary) > delete the iTunes library file > reimport your music into iTunes

Comment: @patrix I know what an inode number is and you are wrong. The xml file does not contain inode numbers but the the itl file does, and that is what iTunes use internally. Rename a music file when iTunes is not running and see for yourself. iTunes will find it. It wouldn't work if your claim was correct. Also see my old hint here http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2003041911193115   So please don't put questions on hold just because your knowledge is lacking.

Comment: Thanks for your patience in teaching me something I didn't know.

Comment: @klanomath I don't use automatic media management and your solution would delete all metadata. I don't understand how anyone could have upvoted it.

Comment: @d-b I add all metadata to the audio files directly and manage all files/folders myself independently from iTunes. Then it's viable solution.

Comment: @klanomath, I do the same thing, that way I can delete the .xml and .itl and rebuild when I need/want to. The only thing I loose it the play count, which I could care less about.

Comment: @klanomath How do you playcount, rating, date added etc to the file?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved this by creating an Automator service. It works like this:

1. Get artist, album and track number. Show the erroneous file in Finder.
2. Store the values above.
3. Find the parent of the file in (1).
4. chmod -x on the parent (4)
5. Do "info" on the track in iTunes. Since the file is inaccessible due to (4) iTunes asks me to locate it.
6. chmod +x on the parent (4)
7. Since my music is sorted /Artist/Album/ I use the values stored above to do a naive guess where it might be to save me some manual labour to browse to the correct folder
8. Manually verify that the correct file is selected. Done.

I don't think I can attach a workflow to this question, otherwise I would be happy to share it.

Comment: You can add screenshots of your Automator workflow.

Comment: The workflow is too extensive for that.

Comment: Who downvoted this solution without posting a motivation?

Answer (score 1):

There is no syscall to change inode numbers directly. So what I would do to accomplish what you probably want is something like

```
for d in <list of impacted directories>; do
    cd "$d"
    for f in *; do
        cp "$f" foo
        rm "$f"
        mv foo "$f"
    done
    cd ..
done
```

Making this fail-proof and avoid data loss in case something goes wrong inside the loop is left as exercise for the reader.